# What gas has the highest refractive index?

Tags: materials

Coming from [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98955/how-dense-of-an-atmosphere-do-i-need-to-float-an-ocean-of-liquid-at-1000-ft-el/98988#98988) on the Worldbuilding stack, I'm trying to find a gas with a high refractive index in the visible light wavelengths. The highest index on [this site](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_5/2_5_7.html), is chlorine at 1.000773. Is this the highest a gas can be? Or is there a fundamental limit on the refractive index of a gas?

As a note, I am *not* looking for the [densest gas](https://www.gasworld.com/tungsten-hexafluoride-the-densest-known-gas/3609.article) or the [densest inert gas](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/which-is-the-densest-gas-known). Density does not seem to be correlated with refractive index in this case, as chlorine is [not especially dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine) and the very dense perfluorobutane is [not especially refractive](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LHCb/C4F10).

Comment: I don't think there is a fundamental limit. Then again, benzene is not a gas at room temperature.

Comment: Well, for a high refractive index (in a simple Lorentz oscillator type of model) both (1) lots of stuff, and (2) lots of electron-photon interactions per bit of stuff. Hard to do with a gas at STP.

Comment: (1) For whatever **gas** it will surely depend on the temperature and pressure. So no real theory to predict it is a matter of looking RI for various gases at that temperature and pressure. (2) Would a supercritical fluid be within scope? For a gas there is not going to be a great density hence fairly small  refractive index. With a supercritical fluid you'd have a lot more matter at the solid surface of a planet.

Comment: [Venus Gets Weirder: CO2 Oceans May Have Covered Surface](https://www.space.com/28112-venus-weird-superfluid-oceans.html)

Comment: If pressure and temperature are specified (and perhaps a more specific wavelength than simply visible), this question might qualify for reopening.

Comment: For those who consider reopening, please see the relevant [meta discussion](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4025/4945).

Answer (score 8):

The question has to be more specific to get a specific answer.

Even in the table linked in the OP, bromine gas (1.001132) has a higher index of refraction than 1.000773.

At zero degrees C, 5462 Angstroms, and atmospheric pressure, [The Refractive Index Dispersion and Polarization of Gases](http://www.jstor.org/stable/96720) (1936) reports:

> $\ce{Si2H6}$ 1.0016574

$\ce{Si2H6}$ , [disilane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disilane), is a gas at room temperature and atmospheric pressure.

The index of refraction is extremely dependent upon pressure.

As an introduction, see [INDEX OF REFRACTION AND DISPERSION OF SEVERAL GASES IN CERENKOV COUNTER USE](https://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/4731864) where indexes of refraction of gases as high as 1.02963 (for 182.79 psig ethane) are measured.